# How to read user input directly in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

From the following code I can read and console.log the line

```
const readline = require('readline');
const { stdin: input, stdout: output } = require('process');

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

rl.question('What is your name? ', (answer) => {
  console.log(`Hi ${answer}!`);

  rl.close();
});
```

But I am trying to read user input like this
Input: `node app.js John`
Ouput: `Hi John!`

How can I achieve this in node?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you can use the following:

```
process.argv
```

process.argv is an array containing all arguments that were used when invoking you programm.
Image you called your programm like that: `node index.js "John"`, process.argv would look like this: `["node", "path/to/index.js", "John"]`.